# nested bracketed expression oracle regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Friends,

I am learning oracle regular expressions. I am using Oracle 12c.
I understand that a bracket expression containing a series of characters returns the first matched character from the input string.

Thus, `select regexp_substr('123 Oracle', '[abc]') from dual`
 returns the chracter `'a'`.
But what if bracket expressions are nested?

```
select regexp_substr('123 Oracle', '[[abc]]') from dual
```

returns `NULL` indicating no match. But Why?

How does oracle interpret this regular expression?
Within the outer `[]` brackets, I expect the inner `[]` brackets to be treated as literals.
So the output should be the first character among the list `[ a b c ]` to be matched.
Once again `regexp_substr` must return `'a'`.  Why is `NULL` returned instead?

A variation on this:

```
select regexp_substr('[]123 Oracle', '[[abc]]') from dual
```

returns `'[]'`.  And I thought that a bracketed expression would always return a single character.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Geetha

Answer (score 0):

`[[abc]]` is not a nested bracket expression. It's simple bracket expression matching `[, a, b, c` followed by single `]`.

[wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions)

[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)